# Article coming up over another article?

Tags: html, css, position

I have the following image slideshow, my problem is that the following articles below this article are coming up over this article and sitting on top of it, where am I going wrong? The slideshow itself is working fine so no problems there.

HTML:

```
<article class="c-all b-all a-all mainImageArticle fade-in one">
<section class="image-slider">
    <div class="fadein">
        <img id="f3" src="landing_image.jpg" alt="Image"/>
        <img id="f2" src="landing_image.jpg" alt="Image"/>
        <img id="f1" src="landing_image.jpg" alt="Image"/>
    </div>
</section>
</article>
```

CSS:

```css
.mainImageArticle {
  position: relative;
}

.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  20% {opacity: 1;}
  33% {opacity: 1;}
  53% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  20% {opacity: 1;}
  33% {opacity: 1;}
  53% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

#f2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

#f3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With no example it's hard to see exactly what's happening, if you was to create a jsfiddle or codepen we might be able to help further.

However, that said, it's likely that you'll need to give the slider container, `image-slider`, a height. As from that code it looks like the things within it are absolutely positioned, which means it's container doesn't know it's own height. Causing whatever is below it to move up into it's place.

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsFiddle using your code and just added one class to you code.

http://jsfiddle.net/7yyuhk03/

**CSS**

```
.mainImageArticle {
  position: relative;
}
img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 160px;
}
.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  20% {opacity: 1;}
  33% {opacity: 1;}
  53% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  20% {opacity: 1;}
  33% {opacity: 1;}
  53% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

#f2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

#f3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}
```

I just added a class for the images and assigned the with and height to it.

**Here is the HTML**

```
<article class="c-all b-all a-all mainImageArticle fade-in one">
<section class="image-slider">
    <div class="fadein">
        <img id="f3" src="http://viralstash.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/521013543_1385596410.jpg" alt="Image"/>
        <img id="f2" src="http://wallpapertodays.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Dogs-Wallpaper-Desktop.jpg" alt="Image"/>
        <img id="f1" src="http://9pixs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/dog-pics_1404159465.jpg" alt="Image"/>
    </div>
</section>
</article>
```